# Match a sequence of bits in a number and then convert the match into zeroes?

Tags: c#

My assignment is to search through the binary representation of a number and replace a matched pattern of another binary representation of a number. If I get a match, I convert the matching bits from the first integer into zeroes and move on.
For example the number 469 would be `111010101` and I have to match it with 5 (`101`). Here's the program I've written so far. Doesn't work as expected.

```
using System;

namespace Conductors
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this is the number I'm searching for a match in
            int binaryTicket = 469;
            //This is the pattern I'm trying to match (101)
            int binaryPerforator = 5;

            string binaryTicket01 = Convert.ToString(binaryTicket, 2);

            bool match = true;
            //in a 32 bit integer, position 29 is the last one I would 
            //search in, since I'm searching for the next 3
            for (int pos = 0; pos < 29; pos++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    var posInBinaryTicket = pos + j;
                    var posInPerforator = j;

                    int bitInBinaryTicket = (binaryTicket & (1 << posInBinaryTicket)) >> posInBinaryTicket;
                    int bitInPerforator = (binaryPerforator & (1 << posInPerforator)) >> posInPerforator;

                    if (bitInBinaryTicket != bitInPerforator)
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //what would be the proper bitwise operator here?
                        bitInBinaryTicket = 0;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(binaryTicket01);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest this be posted @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO. Complete code that doesn't work as you expect it is better reviewed there.

Comment: @Mikanikal CodeReview is for complete code that *does* work, but needs feedback for better/cleaner solutions. It would be closed if OP posted it on codereview. SO is the correct site for this question. However, it's currently unclear as 'not working as expected' can mean a million different things.

Comment: @Rob That was my intention if it did not sound (read) as such. Code that is working, but not as expected, meaning that he needs a better solution. So with a more clear question from the OP, I guess I will retract my comment.

Comment: @Rob The console outputs 29 times `111010101`, even though this CW is outside of the loop. The bits aren't replaced either -`111010*101*`  and `11*101*0101`. The end result should be `110000000`

Comment: @TsvetanDimoff You never change `binaryTicket01`

Comment: What happens with 1101011? Should it be converted to 1000011 or 1100001? BTW, to convert a bit to 0, you must perform an AND operation with a all-1 number except where you want the zero. For example, `binaryTicket & 0xFFFE` will return 468.

Comment: @Andrew 101 The operation takes place from right to left, so the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

1. Use `uint` for this. Makes things a hell of a lot easier when dealing with binary numbers.
2. You aren't really setting anything - you're simply storing information, which is why you're printing out the same number so often.
3. You should loop the x times where x = length of the binary string (not just 29). There's no need for inner loops

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //this is the number I'm searching for a match in
    uint binaryTicket = 469;
    //This is the pattern I'm trying to match (101)
    uint binaryPerforator = 5;

    var numBinaryDigits = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(binaryTicket, 2));
    for (var i = 0; i < numBinaryDigits; i++)
    {
        var perforatorShifted = binaryPerforator << i;

        //We need to mask off the result (otherwise we fail for checking 101 -> 111)
        //The mask will put 1s in each place the perforator is checking.
        var perforDigits = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(perforatorShifted, 2));
        uint mask = (uint)Math.Pow(2, perforDigits) - 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Ticket:\t" + GetBinary(binaryTicket));
        Console.WriteLine("Perfor:\t" + GetBinary(perforatorShifted));
        Console.WriteLine("Mask :\t" + GetBinary(mask));

        if ((binaryTicket & mask) == perforatorShifted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match.");
            //Imagine we have the case:

            //Ticket:
            //111010101
            //Perforator:
            //000000101

            //Is a match. What binary operation can we do to 0-out the final 101?
            //We need to AND it with 
            //111111010

            //To get that value, we need to invert the perforatorShifted
            //000000101
            //XOR
            //111111111
            //EQUALS
            //111111010

            //Which would yield:
            //111010101
            //AND
            //111110000
            //Equals
            //111010000

            var flipped = perforatorShifted ^ ((uint)0xFFFFFFFF);
            binaryTicket = binaryTicket & flipped;
        }
    }

    string binaryTicket01 = Convert.ToString(binaryTicket, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(binaryTicket01);
}

static string GetBinary(uint v)
{
    return Convert.ToString(v, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
}
```

Please read over the above code - if there's anything you don't understand, leave me a comment and I can run through it with you.

Comment: Solution works. Thank you so much! I still haven't wrapped my head around it. I might take advantage of your offer at some point. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TsvetanDimoff No worries. I've updated it with a bit of debugging code, so hopefully you can see how the shifting works and the binary numbers we're working with

Comment: @Rob, I guess you meant `uint` instead of `unit`. I was wondering what you were talking about, LOL.

Comment: @Andrew Yep :) Thanks - I've fixed it now